# Dynamic list from site in hub

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-team-site, hub-site, aggregation

I have a main communication site acting as hub : `Projects`

I have several teams sites in this hub : `Project A`, `Project B`, `Project C`,...

in the main site `Projects`, I have a list that shows different data from the projects : Person in charge, Launch date, Supplier, ...

I would like that the team in charge of the project fill in info in the project site (i.e. `Project A`) and those data are aggregated in a master view in the `Projects` hub site.

I would like to get the functionalities of List (i.e. filters, different views,...)

Is there a way to do that in Sharepoint Office365?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display list from another site collection, for now we can only use [highlighted content web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd) as a workaround. And We do not have functionalities like filters or views.

An example here:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/57439/display-list-from-another-site-collection.html